# Swift: navigationController returning nil

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

On a UIViewController instantiated by a UITabBarController, when I run the following code,

```
let destination = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("test")
self.navigationController!.pushViewController(destination!, animated: true)
```

`navigationController` return nil. How can I get `navigationController` instance to push a view controller?

Comment: Is your UIViewController embedded in a navigation controller in the storyboard?

Comment: No, I forgot to embed it in a navigation controller. After doing that, the code worked. Thanks!

Comment: You should either answer your own question and accept that answer or delete the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As @Paulw11 said, what was missing was embed the `UIViewController` in a navigation controller. To do that, drag-and-drop a `Navigation Controller` to the Storyboard and CTRL + drag from that `Navigation Controller` to the `UIViewController`, chosing the relationship `root view controller`.

Answer (score 1):

Your source `UIViewController` instance needs to be embedded in a `UINavigationController` in the storyboard scene in order to provide a navigation controller instance to push to.

Comment: This would not help if he instantiates the view controller directly.  He would also have to instantiate the nav controller.

Comment: The issue  isn't referring to the destination view controller - the view controller that was instantiated. It is saying that the current view controller (the one that he is trying to push the instantiated view controller onto) doesn't have a navigation controller

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/32959896/3810914

Exactly. If you did, the error would be resolved

[image]

[image]